# Tsukemen ramen broth/soup

Tags: soup, ramen

I have tried the Tsukemen type ramen a few times and I find it fascinating. I want to be able to make it myself.

My questions is: How exactly is it made? Is it made by simply reducing other ramen soups or is there a specific technique involved?

Also, what is the name of the thick noodles that are traditionally served with the Tsukemen soup?

Comment: While I do not have the experience to answer your questions.  You might find this interesting: http://luckypeach.com/?s=Tsukemen

Comment: If you have Netflix, look for *Mind of a Chef* w/ David Chang (it was originally on PBS).  One of the first episodes is all about ramen and they spend some time on Tsukeman, including visiting the place where the style was invented.

Comment: It's a lot of work. [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/02/how-to-make-tonkotsu-ramen-broth-at-home-recipe.html) has covered it extensively.

Comment: Great infor from Serious Eats. But that's Tonkotsu Ramen, not Tsukemen, although I suspect Tsukemen is made the same way, just reduced further and more seasoned.

Comment: +1 13win. Disambiguation: Tonkatsu is a fried pork cutlet. Tonkotsu is pork based dipping noodles. And finally, Tsukemen is the ridiculously fatty, unctuous ramen mentioned in serious eats. 'Mind of a Chef' is a great resource.

Comment: I use to go to a tsukemen restaurant in Tokyo and I've seen sometimes the chef preparing the soup. Mainly, he rescues the pieces of meat from the big pot where he boils the stock and he grinds it with a hand blender in order to make a kind of purée. I guess that this is what thickens the soup... but, of course, as a ramen chef, he will never confess the recipe of his soup, not even under torture. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Tsukeman ramen basically means "Dipping Ramen" which consists of a bowl of ramen noodles and a bowl of broth (dipping sauce) and other edibles such are meat and vegetables.

I have been using David Changs' Momofuku book to create ramen broth, tare, and pork. He has a recipe to make the ramen noodles in there but suggests if you don't have the time just to go buy them. I also store all of this in the freeze until it's time to make ramen dishes.